# Expanded Container resizes after wrapping container with TextButton or any other button

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

**I have wrapped a Container with an expanded widget. There are many containers of that sort but let's look at how one changes as soon as I wrap the container with a Button; it becomes small.**

**why is that? and how can I fix it? I want the size to be just as it was after adding a button.**

```
Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {  },
                child: Container(
                  child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.divide, size: 50,),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xFFFCACC9),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image: How container looks before and after I have added button]

**all the containers but the small one with the division sign in it have no button added**

Answer (score 0):

add width and height in your container to fix it

```
Expanded(
    child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {  },
        child: Container(
            height: 100, // <------- for example 100
            width: 100, // <------- for example 100
            child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.divide, size: 50,),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFFCACC9),
            shape: BoxShape.circle
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I don't think an expanded widget can be sized. thanks